# Two ways to solve limit below?

Tags: limits

Given the limit

$$\lim _{x\to 1} \frac{x^3 - 1}{x^2 + 2x - 3}$$

It's obviously undefined at $x = 1$.
I would usually solve it by

$$\lim _{x\to 1} \frac{x^3 - 1}{x^2 + 2x - 3}$$
$$\lim _{x\to 1} \frac{(x-1)(x^2+x+1)}{(x-1)(x+3)} $$
$$\lim _{x\to 1} \frac{x^2+x+1}{x+3} = \frac{3}{4}$$.

**But why** can't I just plug in $x = 0.999999999$ or $x = 1.0000000001$ and see what the value tends to and solve it that way?

And is that what I am supposed to do when I am tasked to assign a reasonable value at a discontinuity?

Comment: Does $x\to 1$ or $x\to 0$? If the latter, then the value at the last line should be $1/3$ not $3/4$.

Answer (score 0):

When the limit is 0/0 as it is in your case, you can use L'hopital's rule, which states that the limit is the derivative of numerator over the derivative of the denominator. What you was fine, and I'm confused as to what you're having trouble with. You can plug in values approaching from both sides to see how the limit tends (as that is the definition), but this is not always a definitive answer and it much better to use L'hopital's rule or some form of cancellation as you did.

Comment: If the limit is being taken at $x = 0$, the limit can be found by direct substitution.  L'Hopital's Rule would be appropriate if the limit were taken at $x = 1$, although that seems like overkill for this problem.

Comment: I'm sorry I thought that he was asking about it at x=1 as he said it was undefined as x=1 and needed help.